# Ring theoretic properties of the rings $K_0$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring, and $K_0(A)$ its algebraic K-theory ring. Are there are any notable results asserting ring-theoretic properties (being Noetherian, reduced, Krull dimension, etc..) of $K_0(A)$ for a (certain) class of rings $A$? The rings $K_0(A)$ are a special kind of commutative rings (e.g., they are $\lambda$-rings), so one can expect some interesting results.

Comment: In general, it is not Noetherian and not reduced. For example, if $A$ is a reasonable ring, then $K_0(A)$ is reduced if and only if it is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Mohan could you make it more precise? for which $A$ is it not Noetherian? what about the Krull dimension? when is it of finite type? do you know of a reference for this? I searched in vain

Comment: As I said, it is almost never Noetherian or reduced. As a simple example, take the case of $A$, the coordinate ring of a smooth curve (say over complex numbers). Then $K_0(A)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus Pic A$.Further, Pic A is an ideal and its square is zero. If $Pic A\neq 0$, then it is an uncountable group and so $K_0(A)$ is neither Noetherian nor reduced. Similar examples can be constructed for any such rings of larger dimension. In all these cases, $K_0(A)$ has Krull dimension one, since modulo the nilradical, it is just $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: While I know these examples, I was hoping for more general information, making the "almost never" precise.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by general information. Tell me what you know and what you want to know. May be I can give you some thoughts then.

Comment: What I mean are theorems like $K_0(A)$ is Noetherian if and only if .... (some condition on $A$), $K_0(A)$ has finite type if and only if..... (It need not be an equivalence however.) Also is there a formula for the krull dimension of $K_0(A)$ in terms of the krull dimension of $A$ (and other quantities).

Answer (score 2):

Let me write this out as a partial answer. I will work with only $A$ which are co-ordinate rings of an affine open subset of a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Then, as I said, $K_0(A)$ modulo nilpotents is $\mathbb{Z}$ and thus always have Krull dimension one. It is Noetherian if and only if it is a finitely generated  module over $\mathbb{Z}$. Further, if it is Noetherian then $H^i(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ for $i>0$.

Comment: thanks! while it does not answer my question entirely, it is certainly very helpful